# Passing Child Iframe element refrence to parent jQuery object

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, inheritance, iframe

I am stuck in some issue here, i have parent child iframes, i don't want to include jQuery file again in the child iframe, so i did something like this.

```
if ( typeof(jQuery) == "undefined" )
    {
        var jQuery = function ( selector ) { return parent.jQuery( selector, document ); };
    }
```

"document" parameter being passed is the child iframe document object ( correct me if i am wrong) now i need to get the length property to know if there are XXX id element present in the iframe FROM WITH IN the iframe. and it gives me the length as 0, but if i include the jquery file instead of inheriting from parent window, it gives me 1. where i am wrong please guide me.
Below is the code to get the count.

```
jQuery(document).ready(

        function(){
            alert(jQuery( "#facebook_connect_start_now").length);
        }
    );
```

Comment: This will be because the function counts the elements on the parent page and not within the iframe. The reference for the parent function is the parent's window object.

Comment: check the second parameter return parent.jQuery( selector, document );
its sending the child iframe document object to the parent jQuery object, context is local, then why its not working? i don't get this. please explain